# Linear independence constraint qualification

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am struggling to understand the following theorem.

**Theorem.** Suppose that $f$ and $h$ are sufficiently smooth functions on the open set $C$. Let $x \in C$ be a local minimum of $f$ subject to the constraints $h(x) = 0$, $x \in C$. In addition, assume the regularity condition (constraint qualification)

$$h'(x) \ is\ onto$$

Then there exists $\lambda$ (a Lagrange multiplier vector) such that
$$0 = \nabla f(x) + \langle\lambda, h'(x)\rangle.$$

**Question**

What does it mean for $h'(x)$ to be onto at a local min (how can a function be onto at only one point)? and why does linear independence of $\{\nabla h_k(x)\}_k$ imply $h'(x)$ being onto, where $h(x)=[ \ h_1(x) ... h_m(x) \ ]^T$?

Comment: The notation and terminology you’ve quoted here are quite unusual.  Could you cite your source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say that an $m$ by $n$ matrix $A$ is onto if the function

$q(x)=Ax$

is onto $R^{m}$, or equivalently if $\mbox{rank}(A)=m$, or equivalently if $A$ has $m$ linearly independent rows.

For a particular point $x$, $h'(x)$ is the matrix

$h'(x)=\left[
\begin{array}{c}
\nabla h_{1}(x)^{T} \\
\nabla h_{2}(x)^{T} \\
\vdots \\
\nabla h_{m}(x)^{T}
\end{array}
\right]
$

Saying that $h'(x)$ is onto is simply an unusual way of saying that the vectors $\nabla h_{1}(x)$, $\nabla h_{2}(x)$, $\ldots$, $\nabla h_{m}(x)$ are linearly independent.

Comment: but the theorem doesn't state that $h_i(x)$'s are of the form $Ax$?

Comment: This is an abuse of terminology.  Since $A$ is associated with the function $q(x)=Ax$, we say that $A$ is onto if the function $q$ is onto.